# Using foldr function in ML to merge a list of lists

Tags: merge, sml, fold, ml

If I have a set of lists such as [[1,2,4], [3], [0,9,8]...], and assuming routine 'merge' is predefined, how do I merge these lists into one single list using the foldr function?

The syntax for foldr is : foldr f init [...]; I'm confused what the initial condition should be in this case.

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: do you have any thoughts? what would be the result of merging 0 lists?

Answer (score 0):

Using `foldr` to achieve this, you would use `foldr (fn (xs, result) => ...) initial xss` where `initial` is one of the operands to merge (it works as the first `result` while the result of merging works as the subsequent `result`s). That is, its type is a list, and it should have the property that merging it with the first of the sub-lists should result in only the first of the sub-lists. There is only one list that does this.